# MySQL: How to find count for column with joined manytomany table

Tags: mysql

I tried to find a similar question but no answer was helping me. I have 3 tables. `student`, `course` and `student_has_course` (many to many).

Students takes courses and there are courses in 2 different languages. Say english and spanish. I want to find student count for each language. For example: I want to find how many students taking a course in english. I can't figure out how to find this.

EDIT:

table `student`: `ID`, `NAME`
table `course`: `ID`, `LANGUAGE`
table `student_has_course`: `COURSE_ID`, `STUDENT_ID`

Lets say there are 10 courses in total which 5 in english and 5 in spanish. Say there are 100 students in total. 70 of them taking a course in english and 30 of them taking a course in spanish. How do I found number of 70 for students taking a course in english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving us much to work off of, so assuming schema, try this:

```
SELECT
    c.language,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    course AS c
INNER JOIN student_has_course AS shc ON shc.course_id = c.id
GROUP BY
    c.language;
```

If all you want is English

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM
    course AS c
INNER JOIN student_has_course AS shc ON shc.course_id = c.id
WHERE
    c.language = 'English';
```

Comment: Mike, thank you for your answer but I get wrong result with this query. And  shouldn't be something like; `WHERE c.language = 'English'` clause in this query to find student count on english spoken courses?

Comment: What is wrong with the results? You didn't post schema so I had to guess at how the tables are linked. You could add a where clause if all you want is english, my query just gives you a count against all languages.

Comment: Mike, your query works fine but it's not what I was looking for. I edited the question.

Comment: Read your edit, how is the 2nd query not working? The designation for language is on the course table, to which we are joining students via the student_has_course table.

Comment: Np boss. Next time post the relevant schema so we don't have to guess.